# Install Third party library in Prestashop

Tags: jwt, prestashop

I am trying to install a JWT Library (i.e https://github.com/web-token/jwt-framework)  in Prestashop,

I am not sure how to install & use it.

Do i need to run `composer require web-token/jwt-framework` in PS root to install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Composer is installed by default in prestashop versions 1.7+.

If you are starting a new project you can init your composer project along with the dependency:

```
composer init --require="web-token/jwt-framework" -n  
composer install
```

Or if you already have an existing project simply add the dependency:

```
composer require web-token/jwt-framework
```

Then update your composer.json file to include the class in your autoload nad regenerate it:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

(Installing webservice library if u want to see documentation example: [LINK](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/webservice/tutorials/prestashop-webservice-lib/setup-library/))

If u want to use library in your module here is the link to documentation on how to do it: [LINK](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/composer/)

Although you can go to github repo of this library and download it manually.